# Is Railo Best implemented on Linux or Windows?

Tags: windows, linux, coldfusion, railo

Is railo best implemented on a linux or windows server?  Which OS was it designed to work the smoothest?  I'm talking about from installation to development to deployment in real-world.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if this question really makes much sense because overall performance relies mostly on web-server and servlet engine you are using for deployment. Inside that container is basically the same JAR files set (think someone will correct me if I'm wrong here).

It's more up to you to select the preferred environment, Railo will be happy to work anywhere with same performance.

It should be mentioned that Linux hosting services with same hardware characteristics is usually cheaper, so you can invest saved money in additional RAM.

My personal choice is Linux because I feel it more comfortable, secure and flexible, especially when it comes to shell scripting and automating (backups, maintenance, etc). So I'm using it for my local box and VPS deployments with Railo+Resin+Apache2.

Answer (score 7):

Railo is best deployed on the operating system you feel most comfortable working with.

Answer (score 1):

Railo is part of the Java EE stack (and a JBoss project). Java is by nature cross platform and that's a great beauty of it - it leaves that OS and hardware decision to you!

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't disagree with ppshein more. As of the 3.x series vivotech installers, click next, next, next and you're done! The IIS integration is seemless, just like ColdFusion.

Then just create sites in iis7 and include the jakarta virtual directory (as done automatically in default site) and you're running.

We built a tool to add the site, the virtual directory (and a couple other custom ones) and the tomcat config in one go. It will be on riaforge shortly.

Linux and Windows are now a commodity. There is no 'best' OS anymore, just platforms that pretty much do the same thing, based on your preference.

Answer (score 0):

As my experienced, Railo might be the best implement in Linux. It's because of it's so touchy to configure Railo in IIS7 not like in Apache at Linux.

Answer (score 0):

I have to agree with Aaron on this one. Try an install on OS you're most comfortable with.

That said, it depends on what you already have installed. If its a fresh intallation, the good people at Vivotech developed a couple of different installers for both Windows/IIS7 and various flavours of Linux. What's nicer is that they made installers for both Railo and Open BlueDragon. So you're not limited to any one Open source engine. The setup installs Tomcat, Railo/Open Blue Dragon and the necessary connectors to the web server. Here's the link:
http://www.viviotech.net/company/installers.cfm

hth,

larry